# How to check string in a line using if statement?

Tags: shell-script, ksh, string

I am expecting the output as below

```
$ ./test.sh Manifest.txt
test/directory1/dir2/Main
test/directory1/dir2/Main contains Main
test/directory1/dir2/Main have string Main
directory2/dir3
directory2/dir3 dont have string Main
```

I am using script as below

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
for project in $line
do
echo $project
if [[ "$project" =~ ^(Main)$ ]]; then
        echo "$project contain Main"
        exit 1
else
        echo "$project dont have Main"
fi
done
done < "$1"
```

But which is not returning the expected output.

Which gives output as

```
test/directory1/dir2/Main
test/directory1/dir2/Main dont have Main
dir2/dir3
dir2/dir3 dont have Main
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regular expression `^(Main)$` will be matched against the full string in `$project`.  This seems to be a path. The problem is that unless `$project` is *exactly* `Main`, the comparison will fail.  This is because the expression is anchored to both the start and the end of the string.

I believe that simply changing the expression to `Main$` will sort it out for you.  This will match `Main` at the end of the string in `$project`.

Comment: How to cut /Main from the output of above string test/directory1/dir2/Main and assign it to a particular variable ?

Comment: @user2417975 Either `var="$( dirname "$project" )"` or `var="${project##*/}"`.

Comment: Thanks, However the output i am looking here is var=test/directory1/dir2. When i am executing the above command it gives var=Main . Please help

Comment: @user2417975 Yes, I made a mistake. `var="$( dirname "$project" )"` should still be ok, but the alternative should be `var="${project%/*}"`.  This is why I often prefer to use `dirname` and `basename`.

Comment: Hi , How to split after pipe(|) from below and assign to a var  $/dir1/dir2/dir3/Main|$/test1/test2   output should be var=$/test1/test2

Comment: @user2417975 If you have `$/dir1/dir2/dir3/Main|$/test1/test2` in `$var1` then `var2="${var1#*\|}"` will leave `$var2` as `$/test1/test2`.